# Save clicked value of a cell of a table

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to take the value that was clicked from a td of a table? I am having a table that represents a calendar and when I click on a day (on a cell of the table) I want to save that day.

In my html and js code, when I generate the calendar, I use this piece of code:

```
if (i == day && month == cmonth) 
      padding += "<td class='currentday' onclick='saveDate(i);'>" + i + "</td>";
else 
      padding += "<td class='currentmonth' onclick='saveDate(i);''>" + i + "</td>";  


function saveDate(i)
{
    console.log(i);
}
```

Right now my i value is undefined. Is it possible to send this value as a parameter to the function, or is it any other way to save that value?

Comment: Can you post enough of your  ("*[mcve]*") code that we can reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `i` argument using string concatenation:

```js
padding += "<td class='currentday' onclick='saveDate("+i+");'>" + i + "</td>";
```

Here is working code snippet:

```js
let padding = "";
for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
  padding += "<td class='currentday' onclick='saveDate("+i+");'>" + i + "</td>";
}
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = padding;
function saveDate(i)
{
    console.log(i);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr id="main"></tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The procedure we will follow to get your solution is, OnClick we will fetch the Text inside the ID currentday & then POST the data to the URL provided.

```
<td class='currentday' id="currentday" onclick="trythis('currentday');" >Hello</td>


function trythis(e){
var pitt = document.getElementById (e).innerText;


   jQuery.ajax({
   url: "YOUR FILE PATH TO SAVE INFORMATION",
   data:{ pitt: pitt }, 
   type: "POST",
   success:function(data){
   console.log(data);
    $('#response_block').html(data);
    data= [];
    e= [];
    pitt= [];
    },
    error:function (){}
    });
}
```